# Using @Autowired anotation for Interface in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, interface, autowired

I have an interface(QBuilder) and there are two classes(MBuilder, TBuilder) implementing this interface. The interface contains a test method. This method receives parameter type of MCubeInfo in MBuilder and TCubeInfo in TBuilder.

```
public interface QBuilder<T> {

    public String test(T cubeInfo);
}

public class MBuilder implements QBuilder<MCubeInfo> {

    @Override
    public String test(MCubeInfo cubeInfo) {
        System.out.println("MCube Info");
        return "MCube";
    }
}


public class TBuilder implements QBuilder<TCubeInfo> {
        @Override
        public String test(TCubeInfo cubeInfo) {
            System.out.println("TCube Info");
            return "TCube";
        }
}
```

I am expecting that when I call test method in QuerySvc,  qBuilder  redirect to me according to the parameter type. However in autowired QBuilder set automatically with MBuilder. Therefore when I sent TCubeInfo object to the test function, occurs an error that it can not be convert MCubeInfo.

```
@RestController
public class QuerySvc {

     private QBuilder qBuilder;

     @Autowired
     public void setQBuilder(QBuilder q){
          qBuilder = q)
     }

     @RequestMapping(value = "/boot", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public ResponseEntity<String> getTest(){

           .
           .
           .
           TCubeInfo cube = .....
           qBuilder.test(cube);

     }


}
```

When I search the problem, I encountered with @Qualifier annotation but I cannot adapt it to my problem.

Comment: Parameterized bean is a bad option to start with because of type erasure in Java. Your <MCube> and <TCube> will be turned into Object. Refer to: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Name beans - and use appropriate bean names witih QUalifier https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire . You example does not say how you define beans (as Components, or as Beans in configuration).

Comment: Actually,  I cannot use @Qualifier because, it is decided in run time. Can I set qualifier in run time

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make two different beans of these two Service/Component Class that you defined.

```
public class MBuilder   //two different beans in configuration Class.
public class Tuilder
```

> Spring-boot Configuration Class.

```
@Bean(name="mBuilder") //define bean name
public MBuilder mBuilder(){    //mBuilder bean for MBuilder Class.
    return new MBuilder();
}

@Bean(name="tBuilder")   //Define bean name
public TBuilder tBuilder(){   //tBuilder bean for TBuilder Class.
    return new TBuilder();
}
```

Now, In Your `RestController` try to inject two beans with different `@Qualifier` statement. As shown below.

> RestController Class.

```
@RestController
public class QuerySvc {

     @Qualifier("tBuilder")  //Now use tBuilder Object as per Your Need.
     @Autowired
     private QBuilder tBuilder;
     @Qualifier("mBuilder") // You can use mBuilder Object as per need.
     @Autowired 
     private QBuilder mBuilder;

     @Autowired
     public void setQBuilder(QBuilder q){
          qBuilder = q)
     }

     @RequestMapping(value = "/boot", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public ResponseEntity<String> getTest(){

           .
           .
           .
           TCubeInfo cube = .....
           qBuilder.test(cube);
     }
}
```

> **Note** :- Here You Used generics Typed parameters which resolve at Compile Time Only. Here `TCubeInfo` and `MCubeInfo` both are different classes (they are not in relationship heirarchy). So, It is impossible to cast the object which not comes under heirarchy. It will raise `ClassCastException`.

Comment: I encountered with following error:

`Parameter 0 of method setqBuilder in tr.....query.api.controller.QuerySvc required a single bean, but 2 were found:
 - molapBuilder: defined by method 'mBuilder' in tr.....QuerySvcMain
 - mondrianBuilder: defined by method 'tBuilder' in tr...QuerySvcMain


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed`

Comment: @ugur Now answer is updated.. please go through with that

Comment: How can I define qBuilder, do I need to set @Qualifier?

Comment: @ugur `QBuilder` is defined as `tBuilder` and `mBuilder`. It will inject bean according to `@Qualifier` annotation defined.

Comment: @ugur if you find the correct solution by this answer please Mark Tick, so that anybody else can easily find it out in future.. Thanks